# How do we understand the axiom of Choice?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

I was pondering about the infamous statement given by Russell to understand choice, "To choose one sock from an infinitely many pairs of socks one requires axiom of choice, for shoes the axiom is not needed." But my question is, do such 'socks' exist in the Universe of Set Theory? Axiom of Extensionality says that each set should be identified with the sets it constitutes, so it means each sock from any particular pair must have something to distinguish them, so if we have a 'property' to distinguish them, then why do we need Choice?

Comment: The point of the statement is not that you can formally write down a set whose elements are socks. The point is that if you have a uniform way to describe your choice in all sets in question (in the case of shoes, "the left one"; if you were working with sets of positive integers, "the smallest", etc) you do not need AC. But without a way to do so where your choice is truly arbitrary in each instance (e.g. the "socks"; sets of reals; etc), the you need AC.The socks are distinct in each pair (different atoms, say) but this does not provide you with a uniform way to choose across all pairs.

Comment: The question is different in the sense that the OP is questioning whether if we take any random fair of socks, can't we well-order it or not.  I am arguing that given a set S, it has sets inside it (or it is empty) and as the sets contained in S are different they have different 'properties' and whether or not it's possible to use the 'properties' of \textit{all those $s\in S$} to choose a particular member of $S$ not a property of $S$ itself (for example well ordering).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin 's answer made me realize that choice is like a uniform 'property' for all the sets present in our Universe but I must say the 'truly arbitrary in each instance' is kind of unclear to me, if he/she could digress on that it would be really helpful!

Comment: A proof is. *finite* sequence of statements. A statement is itself finite. You do not need AC (or structure) to pick an element from any given set, or from finitely many given sets. The problem is when you need to write down how you are making *infinitely many* choices. You cannot do it one set at a time, even though in any given set you can make a choice, because this process does not "complete". In order to be able to say you have a way to access specific elements in **all** sets, not just any given one, you need AC which provides a finite statement that insures infinitely many choices.

Comment: So, yes, if you take **one** pair of socks you can "well order" it and pick one. You can do that with a hundred pairs. You can doit with a googleplex of pairs. But without AC, you cannot do it for *infinitely many* pairs.

Comment: Ah, it makes sense now, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can prove an arbitrary product $\prod_{i\in I} G_i$ of groups forms a group without axiom of choice, as we can pick identity $e_i\in G_i$ uniformly. And for each element $(a_i)\in \prod_{i\in I} G_i$, we can form $(a_i^{-1})\in\prod_{i\in I}G_i$ without axiom of choice, etc. This corresponds to the intuitive idea that the product of shoes is not empty.

Now given an arbitrary family of sets $S_i$ for $i\in I$, is there an element in $\prod_{i\in I} S_i$? For any specific example you can describe, $S_i$'s almost certainly have some structure to exploit like being shoes rather than socks, so you can prove $\prod_{i\in I} S_i$ is nonempty without axiom of choice. The point of AC is that you don't need to exploit any specific feature of the sets, and you are allowed to assume the product is nonempty. It's unconstructive, but also consistent with ZF.

Similarly, for each vector space you can describe, there is probably some canonical basis based on the context, but we can assume any vector space has a basis without knowning the specifc structure or being able to explicitly exhibit such a basis (because of AC).

As proving such general theorems about specific structures is universal in modern math, one can argue that sets of socks are everywhere. It's not that "socks" exist in the Universe of Sets, but rather in our description of the universe of sets whatever it means.

Comment: The Universal Property here is the existence of an identity in each and every group. I get the allure of having an universal property but I am pretty much conflicted about philosophically accepting choice, because I think the properties that arises from the elements of a set are enough to choose an element from the set in itself.

Comment: If you only have finitely many sets, then yes, you can even pick through syntax. But to choose from infinitely many sets, you can either pick through sematics (like the left shoes, or some kind of "algorithm"), or have to use AC.

Comment: @ArunavoGanguly the term "universal property" has a specific meaning (in Category Theory). Using it in this context is at best likely to cause confusion.

Comment: +1. I was once told by a mathematician that it had been shown to be consistent with ZF that there exists a vector space with 2 Hamel bases that are cardinally incomparable.